# Use scroll only inside certain div

Tags: jquery, scroll

I need to use this scroll to anchor script only in certain page inside certain div.
I have page which have `body class: body.page-id-1` and `div id #main`. So script should work inside: body.page-id-1 #main

```
jQuery('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = jQuery(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    jQuery('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
});
```

I could not get this working with changing `jQuery('html,body').animate` to `jQuery('body.page-id-1 #main').animate`

Any help how to make this script work only in that one page inside certain div?

Comment: Can you set up a working example or at least post some html-markup?